# How to group same columns (different by suffix) using sum in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this. Note of the total_customer columns it has 500+ differentiated by a date suffix.

```
total_customer      total_customer_2021-03-31  total_customer_date X  
1                   10                          4                  
3                   14                          3
```

Now, I want to sum up the columns row-wise that are the same given by removing the date suffix, so this cannot be done manually. I.e the expected output is:

```
total_customer         
15                                             
20
```

The issue why I cannot do this manually is because I have 500+ column pairs, so I need an efficient way to do this. Also, the order of columns is not predictable either. What do you recommend?
Thanks!

Comment: Use: `df.sum(axis=1).to_frame(name='total_customer')`

Comment: There are different groups?

Comment: What means `500+ column pairs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are diffrent groups use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.columns.str.replace('[0-9-_]+$',''), axis=1).sum()
```

Or if need sum all columns only use `sum` like commented:

```
df1 = df.sum(axis=1).to_frame(name='total_customer')
```